# Find positive $a$, $b$ for that function has limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

My problem is to find $a \geq 0$, $b \geq 0$ for for which the following limit: $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \Big(5^{\frac{1}{x}} + \sin(ax^3 + \frac{3 \pi}{2}) + \ln(1 + \frac{e^{bx} - e^{-bx}}{2} ) \Big) $$ exists and equals $0$.

I think that answer is $a=0$, $b=0$. But I do not know how to accurately prove that

- $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \cos(ax^3)$ exists and equals to $1$ only if $a=0$;
- $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \ln \Big(1 + \sinh(bx) \Big)$  exists and equals to $0$ only if $b=0$.

Please help me to prove these two statements. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are right!

Comment: lim cos (ax^3) exists on if a = 0, can be proven by noting on any interval $x \in [\sqrt[3]{{2k\pi}{a}},\sqrt[3]{{2(k+1)\pi}{a}})$, $\cos(ax^3)$ will take on all values from $-1 $ to $1$.  But that doesn't mean the limit of $\cos(ax^3) + g(x)$ doesn't exist if $g(x)$ takes on and "counters" those values.  In this case it doesn't. but....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show that if $a = b = 0$ then $\sin(ax^3 + \frac {3\pi}2) = \sin(\frac 3\pi 2) = 1$ and $\ln{1+\frac{e^{bx} - e^{-bx}}2} = \ln{1} = 0$ are constants and that $\lim 5^{\frac 1x} = 1$.

Thus the limit is $0$ if $a = b = 0$.

If $a \ne 0$ then $\lim \sin(ax^3 + \frac {3\pi}2)$ does not exist as $\sin$ will take on all values of from $-1$ to $1$ repeatedly.  To show this formally, show that for any $M$ there will exist an $x > M$ so that $ax^3 + \frac {3\pi}2 = 2k*\pi + \frac {\pi}2$ for some integer $k$ and a $y > M$ as that $ay^3 + \frac{3\pi}2 = 2j*pi + \frac {3\pi}{2}$ for some integer $j$. so there will always by $x, y > M$ so that $\sin(ax^3 + \frac {3\pi}2) = 1$ and $\sin(ay^3 + \frac {3\pi}2) = -1$)

So if $a\ne 0; b = 0$ there will be no limit.

If $b > 0$ then $e^{bx}=(e^b)^x \rightarrow \infty$ and $e^{-bx} \rightarrow 0$ so $ \ln (1 + \frac {e^{bx} -e^{-bx}}2) \rightarrow \infty$.

So if $b \ne 0$ there will be no limit.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

Also $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}5^{\frac{1}{x}}-1=0$ and you are done!